# Using scala's tools to write a better code

Tags: scala

I am writing a function that determined if a person with the specified `gender` (either "M" or "F") who was born in `birthYear` is expected to be alive, according to a data file (csvData) that looks like this:

("1930, "67", "76")

("1950, "65", "77")

("1970, "64", "76")

where:

*the first number represents a year*

*the second represents the life expectancy of a man*

*the third represents the life expectancy of a woman*

example:

" A man born in 1930 has a life expectancy of 67 years."

```
    def expectedAlive(gender: String, birthYear: Int, currentYear: Int): Boolean = {

  val age = currentYear-birthYear //gets the person's age

  if(gender == "F")//checks for male of female in order to acces the right element 

    if(csvData.contains(birthYear.toString)//checks if year exists in the database

       if(age < csvData.filter(x => x(2).toInt)) //attempts to compare the 3 element in list with age. 

   else...
    else ...
      else ...
```

Here is my issue:

I have looked and asked here about comparing a string to an int. Although I understand why it gives me an error, I don't know how to get around it.
The way I see doing this is by writing if/else statements. However, from I understand Scala has powerful syntax and functions.

Is there a better way to approach this using them?

Comment: Will you please share what your csvData object looks like?

Comment: it's a list just like the one up top

Comment: I'm sorry, you asked for object. It's a variable: val csvData = fromFile("file-name.csv"). It reads straight from file and puts it in a list.

Comment: What do you want as a result if the birth year isn't found in the data?

Comment: I'll thrown an exception. it's not on the code above but it'd be in the else statements

Comment: Looking at your past questions, writing your code by asking a sequence of SO questions isn't terribly efficient. Your time (and ours) might be better spent if you spent an hour or two with a Scala tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
val data = List(List("1930", "67", "76"), 
                List("1950", "65", "77"),
                List("1970", "64", "76"))

def expectedAlive(gender: String, birthYear: Int, currentYear: Int): Boolean = {
  val birthString = birthYear.toString
  val entry = data.find(_(0) == birthString)
  val age = currentYear - birthYear
  entry match {
    case None => true //?? or throw an exception
    case Some(List(_, maleLifespan, femaleLifespan)) => gender match {
      case "M" => age <= maleLifespan.toInt
      case "F" => age <= femaleLifespan.toInt
    }
  }
}
```

Tests:

```
expectedAlive("M", 1930, 1996)                  //> res1: Boolean = true
expectedAlive("M", 1930, 2016)                  //> res2: Boolean = false
expectedAlive("F", 1950, 2015)                  //> res3: Boolean = true
expectedAlive("F", 1950, 2035)                  //> res4: Boolean = false
```

Although with case classes, we can tidy it up a bit:

```
case class Expectancy(year:Int, male:Int, female:Int)

val data = List(List("1930", "67", "76"), 
                List("1950", "65", "77"),
                List("1970", "64", "76"))
val expectancies = data.map(e => Expectancy(e(0).toInt, e(1).toInt, e(2).toInt))

def expectedAlive(gender: String, birthYear: Int, currentYear: Int): Boolean = {
  val age = currentYear - birthYear
  val entry = expectancies.find(_.year == birthYear)
  entry match {
    case None => true //?? or throw an exception
    case Some(e) => gender match {
      case "M" => age <= e.male
      case "F" => age <= e.female
    }
  }
}
```

(passes the tests too)

Comment: How were you able to get around comparing strings and ints? Was it by comparing the age to a new created list (eg case Some (List(_,maleLifeSpan...)?

Comment: The first version has an explicit `maleLifeSpan.toInt` to do the conversion. The second converts the `String`s to `Ints` when it builds the `expectancies` list from the `data` list. So it's always comparing `Ints` to `Int`s (or `String`s to `String`s in the case of `birthString`)